# Почему не отрабатывает onclick в теге button?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, wordpress

Есть [шаблон wordpress Parallax One](http://themeisle.com/demo/?theme=Parallax%20One), в котором меня интересует синяя кнопка **download** в первом экране. при клике на нее - переходит на главную страницу сайта при помощи `onclick`.

```
<button onclick="parent.location='http://themeisle.com/themes/parallax-one/'" 
data-anchor="" class="btn btn-primary standard-button inpage-scroll 
inpage_scroll_btn"> <span class="screen-reader-text">Header button 
label:Download Now</span> Download Now </button>
```

Я установил данный шаблон на свой сайт, указываю в настройках нужный мне переход на ссылку `/gallery` - где-то в теме косяк, не переходит. Ладно, отыскал в коде необходимый мне участок с кодом, прописываю аналогично в `onclick` таким образом

```
<?php $parallax_one_header_button_link = 
get_theme_mod('parallax_one_header_button_link','/gallery');
echo '<button id="inpage_scroll_btn" class="btn btn-primary standard-button
inpage-scroll" onclick="'.$parallax_one_header_button_link.'"><span 
class="screen-reader-text">'.esc_html__('Header button label:',
'parallax-one').$parallax_one_header_button_text.  
'</span>'.$parallax_one_header_button_text.'</button>'; ?>
```

с переменной или указав полный путь `onclick="parent.location='http://themeisle.com/themes/parallax-one/'"` - но `onclick` не отрабатывает и на страницу не переходит, хоть в редакторе отображается путь верно.

Comment: parallax_one_header_button_link - это настройка в шаблоне, поищите, там линк и указывается

Comment: а если в настройке будет пусто, то тогда уже `get_theme_mod` выдаст `/gallery` - то бишь по-умолчанию

Comment: @Blacknife так собственно и да - выдает, что я и указываю: `onclick="parent.location='http://мой_сайт/gallery'` проблема в том, что при клике ничего не происходит и никуда не переходит..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообщем, у меня плохо с экранирование кавычек на `php`, поэтому сделал с помощью `html`

```
<button id="inpage_scroll_btn" class="btn btn-primary standard-button 
inpage-scroll" onclick="parent.location='<?php echo 
$parallax_one_header_button_link; ?>/'"><span class="screen-reader-text">
('Header button label:','parallax-one')<?php echo 
$parallax_one_header_button_text; ?></span><?php echo 
$parallax_one_header_button_text; ?></button>
```